# SAS : Output from highest variable from dataset

Tags: variables, sas, max

I want to assign a new variable from existing highest n variable. 
So if we have a table that has increasing number of columns -

```
data have;
input uid $ var1 $ var2 $ var3 $;
datalines;                      
1111    1   0   1
2222    1   0   0
3333    0   0   0
4444    1   1   1
5555    0   0   0
6666    1   1   1
;
```

I want derive the variable var3 as final_code.

```
data want;
set have;
final_code = max(of var1-var3);
run;
```

Above doesn't make sense here as I want only var3 column to remain. Similarly, if var4 is there, I wish to have var4 only.

Does somebody want to help me here ?

Comment: You want just the value that's in `var3`?

Comment: yes. If there had been a var4, i'd want var4 and so on.

Comment: Your dataset can't have changing number of variables so I suspect these solutions won't work for your full dataset. Can you show exactly what you want and a more complex same data.

Comment: If files are received such that the dataset is replaced again and again with increasing number of columns, then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you don't want `max` of the *values* but the value from the highest-numbered-variable.

Lots of ways to do this, which way depends on how the variables are named.  Here's the easiest, if they're actually named as you say.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array var[*] var:;
  final_code = var[dim(var)];
run;
```

Here we make an array out of `var:` and then choose the last element in the array using `dim` (to say the size of the array).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for is:

```
%let n=3
data want;
set have;
var&n = max(of var1-var&n);
drop var1-var%eval(&n-1);
run;
```

The macro variable `&n` holds the value of n.  This acts as a substitution during the compilation phase of the code.

The `DROP` statement tells the data step to drop those variable.

The `%eval()` macro function performs integer math on macro values. So we are dropping 1 through N-1.

Comment: what if  n=12 and still i want the value from #var3 ? @DomPazz, thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking.  Can you explain with a little more detail?

Comment: based on the comments above @joe answer is what you are looking for.